# Why do url variables cause issues with ajax relative url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, relative-url

So, I'm doing a normal ajax call like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: this.Controller + "/" + this.Action,
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
        $("#Debug").html(JSON.stringify(json, undefined, 4));
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        var errorMessage = "Unable to retrieve data."
        if (jqXHR.responseText != null) {
            errorMessage += "\n\nError Message: " + jqXHR.responseText;
        }
        alert(errorMessage);
    }
});
```

When I use a relative path for the ajax url, it works fine, as long as there are no url variables in the current page's url.  It will correctly go to `http://domain.com/controller/action`

If there is a url variable, the ajax url tries to hit `http://domain.com/controller/controller/action`, which does not exist.

If I add a slash like so:

```
url: "/" + this.Controller + "/" + this.Action
```

This fixes the issue of that the url variables cause, but only locally.  When I deploy to our servers, my app is located in a sub-directory, so the url is `http://domain.com/myapp`.  The slash solution does not work as the root is `http://domain.com` and not `http://domain.com/myapp`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this `$.ajax({url: document.domain + this.Controller ... })` .

Comment: The solution needs to work both locally and on the server.  So, while testing locally, document.domain returns localhost.  When doing it the way you have above, it tries to hit the url `http://localhost:#####/localhostcontroller/action`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all kinds of ways to do this via JS and none of them worked for both server (with sub-directory) and local (without).

So, my **solution** was to add the name of the sub-directory in my web.config's appsettings.  In the main web.config, I have: `<add key="Subdirectory" value="" />`

In the web.release.config, I have: `<add key="Subdirectory" value="SubDirectoryName" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />`

By leaving it blank in the web.config and setting it in web.release.config, the sub-directory will be transformed and set only when published to the server.

On the _Layout.cshtml page, I have:

`<script>
        var subdirectory = '@ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Subdirectory"]';
        if (subdirectory != '') {
            subdirectory = '/' + subdirectory;
        }
</script>`

Then, anywhere in my JS that I am trying to do an ajax call, I set the url to:

`url: subdirectory + "/" + this.Controller + "/" + this.Action,  // subdirectory comes from _Layout.cshtml`